# Is it possible to represent all functions as a boolean function?

Tags: logic

Is it possible to represent all functions (not only binary functions) as a boolean function?

For example, it is possible to implement Function "sum of 2 numbers ($n$ bit)" by having a boolean function for "sum" and another boolean function for "carry".

But is it the case for all? Can we represent all functions by boolean functions?

If it is not possible, which functions can not be represented as a boolean function?

If it is possible, what could be the maximum number of implicants for any function with $n$ variables $x_1, x_2, ..., x_n$ bits as input and $m$ variables $y_1, y_2, ..., y_m$ bits as output?

Answer (score 0):

All binary functions can be represented using AND, OR, and NOT gates.

Let $f$ be some function of the binary variables $X_1, ..., X_n$. Consider the truth table of $f$. Each row corresponds to some conjunction of the form $X_1^*\wedge...\wedge X_n^*$, where $X_i^*$ can be either $X_i$ or $\neg X_i$. $f$ can then be expressed as the disjunction of these expressions over all rows for which $f$ is true. This is called the disjunctive normal form of $f$.

For example, if the truth table is

```
 X1 | X2 | f
 0  | 0  | 1
 0  | 1  | 1
 1  | 0  | 0
 1  | 1  | 0
```

then we have $f(X_1, X_2)=(\neg X_1\land\neg X_2)\lor(\neg X_1\land X_2)$. We're basically just listing all of the rows of the truth table for which $f$ is true, and saying in logical notation "$f$ is true when we're on one of these rows".

Comment: It is only for binary functions, but actually the question is for all functions not only binaries.

Comment: @Elahe But how could you possibly represent a non-binary function using logic gates? Do you have an example to illustrate what you mean?

Comment: Yes, as I have mentioned above, Function "SUM" is not a binary function. The output of this function is a number (in binary representation). But for every single bit of the output, we can have a boolean function (Sum and carry).

Comment: @Elahe What you're talking about are what I would call binary functions with "multiple outputs", or in other words functions that output binary vectors. But you can just think of this as several simple binary functions, so you can still represent this using logic gates. i.e. if $f(X_1, X_2)=(Y_1, Y_2)$, you can think of $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ as each being a simple binary function, and represent each individually using logic gates.

Comment: Exactly. and now I'm looking to find the maximum number of implements one requires to represent such a function.